# Custom dropdown item layout has no effect in Android

Tags: android

I tried to create a custom dopdown item layout to make the items have more space between them. 
Originally I had this code:

```
MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter (this, tmpData);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

And this was the built-in layout of Android:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

I modified the code to this:

```
MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter (this, tmpData);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

And used this layout:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@android:id/text1"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:ellipsize="marquee"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    />
```

Nothing has changed.

Can you tell me why?

Comment: You need to make use of another custom XML file for achieving this. Can you show that file?

Comment: What XML do you mean? The layout contains only that CheckedTextView.

Comment: Are you not using "R.layout.custom_simple_spinner_dropdown_item" ? Seems you are missing "R.". Isn't that giving you error?

Comment: what AdapterView are you using?

Comment: @Dhaval: I was using it, just misspelled.

Comment: @psking: It extends ArrayAdapter<Data>. Strange: I have a getView where I set the original view and the setDropDownViewResource is called later, yet it has no effect. I alter it for a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out the I set the dropdown view at 2 places and the second one is used.
I reckon, when the dropdown is shown, it calls the getDropDownView method so it overrides the first settings. It makes sense.

I create the adapter with a custom dropwdown:

```
MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter (this, tmpData);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

And I override it with the default view:

```
 @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                              ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
```

So when I change it to this, it works:

```
@Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                              ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
```